# $|\max_x f(x) - \max_x g(x)| \le \max_x |f(x) - g(x)|$ is it true?

Tags: analysis

For some continuous functions $f(x), g(x)$ over some interval $[a,b]$,
$$|\max_x f(x) - \max_x g(x)| \le \max_x |f(x) - g(x)|$$ is it true?

For several examples (e.g., $f(x) = x, g(x) = -x$) that I can come up with, it is true but I cannot prove it :(

Comment: The questions in the title and in the body are different.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i have corrected it!

Answer (score 2):

Let $M(f) = \max_{a \le x \le b} f(x)$, which is defined as $f$ is continuous on a compact set.

Given $x \in [a, b]$, we have $f(x) - g(x) \le |f(x) - g(x)| \le M(|f - g|)$, so $f(x) \le g(x) + M(|f - g|) \le M(g) + M(|f - g|)$.

It follows that $M(f) \le M(g) + M(|f - g|)$. Changing $f$ with $g$, we arrive at the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

It is true.  Denote $[a, b]$ by $I$, then
\begin{align}
  & \max_{x \in I}f(x) - \max_{x \in I} g(x) \\
 =& \max_{x \in I}(f(x) - g(x) + g(x)) - \max_{x \in I}g(x) \\
 \leq& \max_{x \in I}(f(x) - g(x)) + \max_{x \in I}g(x) - \max_{x \in I}g(x) \\
 =& \max_{x \in I}(f(x) - g(x)) \leq \max_{x \in I}|f(x) - g(x)| \tag{1}
\end{align}
Here we used the inequality $\max(f_1(x) + f_2(x)) \leq \max f_1(x) + \max f_2(x)$. Interchanging the positions of $f$ and $g$ in $(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
  \max_{x \in I}g(x) - \max_{x \in I} f(x)\leq \max_{x \in I}|f(x) - g(x)| \tag{2}
\end{align}
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
\begin{align}
  |\max_{x \in I}f(x) - \max_{x \in I} g(x)| \leq \max_{x \in I}|f(x) - g(x)|.
\end{align}

The continuity assumption of $f$ and $g$ seems not needed.

Comment: wow thank you, awesome

Comment: I think it is worth noting that it is necessary for the functions to attain a maximum in $I$, which is guaranteed if the functions are continuous. (although continuity is not needed).

Comment: @IgnacioHenríquez Make sense.  The continuity is to guarantee the notation "$\max$" is meaningful.

Comment: @Jayboy If the answer is useful to you, please accept it.